# Latent Dirichlet Allocation Posterior Inference

Tags: performance, julia

I have implemented [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) in Julia. Since the code is rather long, I copied the essential part here but the complete code can be found on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/odinay/3e49d50ba580a9bff8e3).

```
#=
LDA.jl

Adham Beyki, odinay@gmail.com
=#

##########################################
###### Latent Dirichlet Allocation ######
##########################################
type LDA{T}
    bayesian_component::T
    K::Int
    aa::Float64

    LDA{T}(c::T, K::Int64, aa::Float64) = new(c, K, aa)
end
LDA{T}(c::T, K::Int64, aa::Real) = LDA{typeof(c)}(c, K, convert(Float64,    aa))

function Base.show(io::IO, lda::LDA)
    println(io, "Latent Dirichlet Allocation model with $(lda.K) $(typeof(lda.bayesian_component)) components")
end

function initialize_gibbs_sampler!(lda::LDA, zz::Vector{Vector{Int64}})
  # populates the cluster labels randomly
    n_groups = length(zz)
    n_group_j = [length(zz[jj]) for jj = 1:n_groups]
    for jj = 1:n_groups
    zz[jj] = rand(1:lda.K, n_group_j[jj])
    end
end

function LDA_sample_pp{T1, T2}(
    bayesian_components::Vector{T1},
    xx::T2,
    nn::Array{Float64, 2},
    jj::Int64,
    aa::Float64)

  K = length(bayesian_components)
  pp = zeros(Float64, K)
  @inbounds for kk = 1:K
    pp[kk] = log(nn[jj, kk] + aa) + logpredictive(bayesian_components[kk], xx)
  end

  normalize_pp!(pp)
  return sample(pp)
end

function collapsed_gibbs_sampler!{T1, T2}(
    lda::LDA{T1},
    xx::Vector{Vector{T2}},
    zz::Vector{Vector{Int64}},
    n_burnins::Int64, n_lags::Int64, n_samples::Int64)

    n_groups = length(xx)
    n_group_j = [length(zz[jj]) for jj = 1:n_groups]
    nn = zeros(Float64, n_groups, lda.K)
    lda_aa = fill(lda.aa, lda.K)
    n_iterations = n_burnins + (n_samples)*(n_lags+1)
    bayesian_components = [deepcopy(lda.bayesian_component) for k = 1:lda.K]
    pp = zeros(Float64, length(lda.K))

    tic()
    for jj = 1:n_groups
        for ii = 1:n_group_j[jj]
            kk = zz[jj][ii]
            additem(bayesian_components[kk], xx[jj][ii])
            nn[jj, kk] += 1
        end
    end
    elapsed_time = toq()

    for iteration = 1:n_iterations
        println("iteration: $iteration, number of components: $(lda.K), elapsed time: $elapsed_time")

        tic()
        @inbounds for jj = 1:n_groups
            @inbounds for ii = 1:n_group_j[jj]
            kk = zz[jj][ii]
            delitem(bayesian_components[kk], xx[jj][ii])
            nn[jj, kk] -= 1

            kk = LDA_sample_pp(bayesian_components, xx[jj][ii], nn, jj, lda.aa)
            zz[jj][ii] = kk
            additem(bayesian_components[kk], xx[jj][ii])
            nn[jj, kk] += 1
            end
        end
        elapsed_time = toq()
    end
end

function posterior{T1, T2}(lda::LDA{T1}, xx::Vector{Vector{T2}}, zz::Vector{Vector{Int64}})
    n_groups = length(xx)
    bayesian_components = [deepcopy(lda.bayesian_component) for k = 1:lda.K]
    n_group_j = [length(zz[jj]) for jj = 1:n_groups]
    nn = zeros(Int64, n_groups, lda.K)

    for jj = 1:n_groups
        for ii = 1:n_group_j[jj]
            kk = zz[jj][ii]
            additem(bayesian_components[kk], xx[jj][ii])
            nn[jj, kk] += 1
        end
    end

  return([posterior(bayesian_components[kk]) for kk =1:lda.K], nn)
end
```

The Julia implementation is almost 100 times faster than Python (NumPy). For instance, for a simulated dataset from 5 clusters with 1000 observations, each containing 100 points:

```
true_KK = 5
n_groups = 1000
n_group_j = 100 * ones(Int64, n_groups)
```

Julia spends just under 0.1 sec for each LDA Gibbs sampling iteration while it takes almost 9.5 sec in Python on my machine.

But the code is still slow for realistic data sets. For example, for a slightly bigger dataset such as:

```
true_KK = 20
n_groups = 1000
n_group_j = 1000 * ones(Int64, n_groups)
```

The output is:

```
iteration: 98, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 3.209459973                    
iteration: 99, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 3.265090272                    
iteration: 100, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 3.204902689                   
elapsed time: 332.600401208 seconds (20800255280 bytes allocated, 12.87% gc time)
```

As I move to more complex models, optimizing the code becomes a bigger concern. I know that Inference with Gibbs sampling is expensive in nature but since I am new to Julia, I was wondering if someone can go through the code and see if more tweaks can be done.

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.3.11
Commit 483dbf5* (2015-07-27 06:18 UTC)
Platform Info:
  System: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
  LAPACK: libopenblas
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a newbee of Julia so cannot comment on good Julian ways of optimization. But when I tried running your code, I noticed that the major part of computational time is spent on the evaluation of exp() and log() rather than array handling etc. Below, I changed the iteration number in demo_LDA.jl to perform the test quickly as

```
#... In demo_LDA.jl
collapsed_gibbs_sampler!(lda, xx, zz, 0, 0, 1)
@time collapsed_gibbs_sampler!(lda, xx, zz, 0, 0, 5)
```

The result of the original code (using Julia 0.4.0-pre, see below) is

```
iteration: 1, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 0.009839647
iteration: 1, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 0.009694991
iteration: 2, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 2.690772589
iteration: 3, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 2.670282622
iteration: 4, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 2.66571178
iteration: 5, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 2.666383962
13.366990 seconds (5.00 M allocations: 1.043 GB, 0.23% gc time)
```

So it should take about 260-270 sec for 100 iterations. Next, I modified the function `posterior()` in conjugates.jl to make the operation count a bit fewer.

```
function posterior(me::Gaussian1DGaussian1D)
    xbar = me.mu

    if me.nn>0
        # mu = me.v0*xbar / (me.vv/me.nn + me.v0) + (me.vv/me.nn) * me.m0 / (me.vv/me.nn + me.v0)
        # vv = (me.vv*me.v0/me.nn) / (me.vv/me.nn + me.v0)

        #>>> modified part (start)
        tmp1 = me.vv / me.nn
        tmp2 = 1.0 / ( tmp1 + me.v0 )

        mu = ( me.v0 * xbar + tmp1 * me.m0 ) * tmp2        
        vv = me.v0 * tmp1 * tmp2
        #<<<< (end)
    else
        mu = me.m0
        vv = me.v0
    end

    return Gaussian1D(mu, vv)
end
```

Then the result changed as

```
iteration: 1, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 0.009504789
iteration: 1, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 0.009608533
iteration: 2, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 2.351606166
...
iteration: 5, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 2.345334333
11.742193 seconds (5.00 M allocations: 1.043 GB, 0.25% gc time)
```

Next, I modified `logpredictive()` in conjugate.jl such that

```
function logpredictive(me::Gaussian1DGaussian1D, xx::Float64)

    gg = posterior(me)
    mu = gg.mu
    vv = gg.vv

#   ll = exp(-(xx - mu)^2 / (2*(vv + me.vv))) / sqrt(2*pi * (vv + me.vv))
#   return log(ll)

    #>>> modified part (start)
    tmp = vv + me.vv
    val = -(xx - mu)^2 / (2 * tmp) - 0.5 * log( 2*pi * tmp )
    return val
    #<<< (end)
 end
```

Then the result becomes

```
iteration: 1, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 0.009714609
iteration: 1, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 0.009562715
iteration: 2, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 1.409258263
...
iteration: 5, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 1.40165818
  7.022493 seconds (5.00 M allocations: 1.043 GB, 0.43% gc time)
```

Further, I changed the code artificially such that all the exp(x) and log(x) were removed (by simply replacing with x) in the above routines as well as in sample() and LDA_sample_pp(). The result is

```
iteration: 1, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 0.009678183
iteration: 1, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 0.009703009
iteration: 2, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 0.49649945
...
iteration: 5, number of components: 20, elapsed time: 0.496507961
  2.492949 seconds (5.00 M allocations: 1.043 GB, 1.25% gc time)
```

This suggests that a rather large fraction of computation is spent on exp() and log(). So I think that, to get a significant speed up, it might be useful to reduce the net computational cost of exp/log evaluation, in addition to any algorithmic improvement, parallel calculation, or more Julian ways of optimization. (I also tried attaching @inline to some functions, but it did not give much improvement.)

Below is the version info for my environment:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.4.0-pre+7176
Commit 65d7954 (2015-09-04 06:48 UTC)
  Platform Info:
  System: Linux (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v2 @ 2.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
  LAPACK: libopenblas
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3
```

---

Edit

I have tried [Yeppp!](http://www.yeppp.info/) library for fast math functions (Julia's package is [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Yeppp.jl)) with the following code.

```
using Yeppp

function test( n::Int )

    x = rand( n ) + 1.0
    @time y = exp( x )   # Julia's native exp()                                     

    y_yep = zeros( n )
    @time Yeppp.exp!( y_yep, x )    # use Yeppp library                             

    @show sum( abs( y_yep - y ) )   # check the difference                          

    # @show x[ 1:3 ]    # very large array, don't print all!                         
    # @show y[ 1:3 ]                                                                 
    # @show y_yep[ 1:3 ]                                                             
end

test( 10 )  # warm-up
test( 10^6 )
```

The result is

```
  0.000004 seconds (1 allocation: 144 bytes)
  0.000007 seconds
sum(abs(y_yep - y)) = 0.0
  0.016960 seconds (2 allocations: 7.629 MB)
  0.001972 seconds
sum(abs(y_yep - y)) = 4.502620498669785e-11
```

As seen, this library seems much faster than the native math functions (about 8 times in the above example) as long as data arrays are sufficiently large. So, if your code can be rearranged so that many values of exp() or log() are calculated at once, then you may be able to to get a pretty large acceleration.

Comment: Please note that I'm not trying to say that Julia's exp() and log() are slow (rather, they seem to be very fast, as compared with gfortran). The following pages may also be useful https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8869 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/dl_ysr1TdXE/discussion

Comment: Oh yeah. Since I had converted math equations to code I even didn't even notice reformulating the equations could help. I have also fixed the memory allocation. Plz see my anser.

Comment: I did a bit more test with the Yeppp! library (a fast math library) and it does seem to be pretty fast (see the Edit above). I may also use this if I need a lot of exp() etc. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @roygvib one thing that helps is reformulating the math equations. I also fixed the memory problem. here is the parts that I changed.

```
function LDA_sample_pp{T1, T2}(
    bayesian_components::Vector{T1},
    xx::T2,
    nn::Array{Float64, 2},
    pp::Vector{Float64},
    aa::Float64,
    jj::Int64)

  K = length(pp)
  @inbounds for kk = 1:K
    pp[kk] = log(nn[jj, kk] + aa) + logpredictive(bayesian_components[kk], xx)
  end

  normalize_pp!(pp)
  return sample(pp)
end

function collapsed_gibbs_sampler!{T1, T2}(
    lda::LDA{T1},
    xx::Vector{Vector{T2}},
    zz::Vector{Vector{Int64}},
    n_burnins::Int64, n_lags::Int64, n_samples::Int64)

  n_groups = length(xx)
  n_group_j = [length(zz[jj]) for jj = 1:n_groups]
  nn = zeros(Float64, n_groups, lda.K)
  lda_aa = fill(lda.aa, lda.K)
  n_iterations = n_burnins + (n_samples)*(n_lags+1)
  bayesian_components = [deepcopy(lda.bayesian_component) for k = 1:lda.K]
  pp = zeros(Float64, lda.K)

  tic()
  for jj = 1:n_groups
    for ii = 1:n_group_j[jj]
      kk = zz[jj][ii]
      additem(bayesian_components[kk], xx[jj][ii])
      nn[jj, kk] += 1
    end
  end
  elapsed_time = toq()

  for iteration = 1:n_iterations
    println("iteration: $iteration, number of components: $(lda.K), elapsed time: $elapsed_time")

    tic()

    @inbounds for jj = 1:n_groups
      @inbounds for ii = 1:n_group_j[jj]
      kk = zz[jj][ii]
      delitem(bayesian_components[kk], xx[jj][ii])
      nn[jj, kk] -= 1

      kk = LDA_sample_pp(bayesian_components, xx[jj][ii], nn, pp, lda.aa, jj)
      zz[jj][ii] = kk
      additem(bayesian_components[kk], xx[jj][ii])
      nn[jj, kk] += 1
      end
    end
    elapsed_time = toq()
  end
end
```